# JSONArray getValue

Tags: java, json

i have a `teams.json` file with following content

```
{
"league": "Champions League",
"season": "2015/16",
"start": "2015-11-01",
"end": "2016-03-31",
"teams": [ 
    { "name": "Spain" },
    { "name": "Germany"},
    { "name": "Italy" },
    { "name": "Brasil" },
    { "name": "Argentina" }
]
```

}

and i have JSONArray which works fine

```
    JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
    JSONArray teamList = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("teams");
    Iterator<JSONArray> iterator = teamList.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(iterator.next());
        }
```

Output:

```
{"name":"Spain"}
{"name":"Germany"}
{"name":"Italy"}
{"name":"Brasil"}
{"name":"Argentina"}
```

But i just want the values in the Array without the {"name": ... stuff,
like

Spain, Germany,Italy,Brasil,Argentina

Comment: https://github.com/mohit008/Android-Json-Example

Answer (score 0):

You can do this :

```
package foo.bar;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class JSON {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String str = "{\r\n\"league\": \"Champions League\",\r\n\"season\": \"2015/16\",\r\n\"start\": \"2015-11-01\",\r\n\"end\": \"2016-03-31\",\r\n\"teams\": [ \r\n    { \"name\": \"Spain\" },\r\n    { \"name\": \"Germany\"},\r\n    { \"name\": \"Italy\" },\r\n    { \"name\": \"Brasil\" },\r\n    { \"name\": \"Argentina\" }\r\n]}";
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(str);
        JSONArray teamList = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("teams");
        for (Object o : teamList) {
            JSONObject team = (JSONObject) o;
            System.out.println(team.getString("name"));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope it will help you..!

```
 JSONArray teams=new JSONObject(jsondata).getJSONArray("teams");  
  for(int i=0;i<teams.length();i++){  
    JSONObject team=teams.getJSONObject(i);  
    System.out.println("value of name=="+team.getString("name"));  


}
```

Answer (score 0):

just create helper method for getting array.

```
package com.example.helloworld;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MyTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException {
        String str = "{'league': 'Champions League','season': '2015/16','start': '2015-11-01','end': '2016-03-31','teams': [ \r\n    { 'name': 'Spain' },\r\n    { 'name': 'Germany'},\r\n    { 'name': 'Italy' },\r\n    { 'name': 'Brasil' },\r\n    { 'name': 'Argentina' }\r\n]}";

        System.out.println(getCountyList(str).toString());
    }

    public static List<String> getCountyList(String json) throws JSONException {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
        JSONArray teamList = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("teams");
        for (int i = 0, len = teamList.length(); i < len; i++) {
            JSONObject team = (JSONObject) teamList.get(i);
            list.add((String) team.get("name"));
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```